# Can I send post to someone on a cruise ship?

Tags: sea-travel, mail, ships

My Significant Other is currently working on a cruise ship. I happen to be on a separate (family) holiday and thought it would be nice to send her a post card. Can I send post, such as a letter or post card to a cruise ship, or to the port/next port the ship will be docked at?

Would either be practical?

Comment: You'll possibly get a more accurate answer from your SO if she asks her managers

Comment: I would not expect a card to arrive within a few days, so a port further down the route might be a better choice. It is quite common to address mail to someone 'aboard name vessel' with the address as the location the ship docks, if known. It might be easier to address the mail to an office of the cruise company if they have one in one of their stops.

Comment: Postcards can be extremely slow to deliver, 2 to 3 weeks is common depending on the route.

Comment: I did find this: https://www.eurosender.com/en/cp/care-package/crew-member , it does make it look like it's very easy. It even describes the needed information like what to put on the parcel as the receiver.

Comment: @Midavalo, but that would take away the element of surprise

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With ubiquitous electronic communication, it is not really common anymore to send letters or post cards to ship crew, but parcels are still adressable and probably still not too uncommon for birthdays or other holidays if you have a loved one working on a ship. If parcels arrive, I would very much assume that it is still possible to use the same way for letters.

The common procedure, but shipping companies may for sure have different policies on how to handle mail adressed to their crew, is to send the parcel (or letter) to an upcoming port and use an address similar to:

> Ship name
> Attention of: crew member name
> Port's full address

Be aware that international delivery of both letters and parcels may take quite some time, so make sure that you plan plenty of time for the delivery to arrive at the port. If you send a parcel, it should contain nothing with relevance for custom's clearance to make sure that it is delivered to the port without any custom processing.

Comment: Again I would recommend the SO ask for official guidance here.  Sending mail to a cruise ship of 1500+ crew is a bit different from sending to a freighter with 8 crew and they may have policies on how, when, and where this is handled

Comment: It ruins the surprise, if any, though.

Comment: @Midavalo I would guess that nowadays, even in a cruise with 1500 crew, very few letters are received if any.

Answer (score 17):

Yes, but procedure could be different for every cruise line.

The 'big three' all maintain PO Boxes at their Headquarters which are then forwarded to the ship.

For example: [Royal Caribbean Crew Mailing Addresses for Letters and Packages](https://crew-center.com/royal-caribbean-crew-mailing-addresses-letters-and-packages)

Answer (score 5):

From [cruiseindustrynews.com](https://cruiseindustrynews.com/cruise-news/2021/06/return-to-sender-how-easy-is-it-for-crew-member-to-receive-mail/)

> the cruise line’s HR department would be able to provide the address
> of the crew store in the home port

Your SO can collect the letter/packet in the crew store.